# Matlabs permutations of tridiagonal matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation

In Matlab, I need to create all possible 3x3 tridiagonal matrices with elements being either 0 or 1. How would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: I think there are only 4 possible results. Can't you just code them by hand, since they're so small and so few?

Comment: @gnovice I count 4, or 2^3, or 2^9 depending on your definition.

Comment: @beaker: I assumed each matrix had to have 3 diagonals filled with 1. I guess if each diagonal isn't completely filled with 1, you get more permutations.

Comment: Doesn't 3x3 tridiagonal mean that elements (3,1) and (1,3) are zero? In this case, there are 7 remaining elements which can be 0 or 1, right?

Comment: @Florian Yes, you're right. 2^7, not 2^9.

Comment: @Florian: Ahhh, I misunderstood tridiagonal. I was thinking "3 diagonals", but in reality it is just the ones above and below the main.

Comment: @Claire As you can see, we're having some trouble deciding what you're actually looking for. Please clarify what your expected output is and add any code you currently have. Please also read [ask].

Comment: I have a 3x3 tridiagonal matrix ( a matrix that has nonzero elements only on the main diagonal, the first diagonal below this, and the first diagonal above the main diagonal). The only values the elements can take are either 0 or 1. I need to find all possible permutations of this type of matrix with this parameter.

Comment: @Claire In that case, Boris T's answer seems to give you all of the permutations.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it strait forward:

```
x1 = dec2bin(0:127) == '1';
x2 = [x1(:, 1:2) zeros(128, 1) x1(:, 3:5) zeros(128, 1) x1(:, 6:end)];
x3 = arrayfun(@(k) reshape(x2(k, :), [3 3]), 1:128, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

x3 is now cell array with all 3x3 tridiagonal matrices.

Comment: Thank you @BorisT. I appreciate that. Just in case I need to exapnd the matrices (ie change their sizes) later, could you explain each line, as I am unfamiliar with some of that code?

Comment: @BorisT.I appreciate that. Just in case I need to expand the matrices (ie change their sizes) later, could you explain each line, as I am unfamiliar with some of that code?